# How to identify the communication protocol used in a wireless device?

Tags: penetration-test, wireless, wireshark, sniffer, signal-analysis

I really hope that this is the right place to ask.

I need to analyze a baby monitor for any security or privacy weaknesses.

The spec sheet of the baby monitor says, that it uses the ISM 2400~2483.5 MHz bands to transfer video and audio information between camera and monitor. It also uses FHSS and GFSK, which makes me believe that it could be using something like Bluetooth or Zigbee as the protocol.
I've got my hands on a SDR (HackRF) and had a look at the radio waves of the baby monitor via SDRSharp. I would like to find out the communication protocol so that I can try to piece together the signals and maybe decipher or deny information.

I have no idea how to identify what kind of communication protocol is used. I tried using Wireshark to check if it's just simple IP packages but received nothing on that end.

I don't even know whether or not this approach is the right one. I would use the identified protocol to look up the specifications and to understand the frequency hopping function so that I can try to record the signals at the right frequencies.

Some tip or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Likely to be an 802 series wi-fi standard, freq hopping is included in some versions. The 2ghz ism band is commonly used.

Comment: Typically your baby monitors use similar technology to cordless landline phones. Based on the FHSS/GFSK combination you specify, it is likely some sort of [DECT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Enhanced_Cordless_Telecommunications) device.